# Displaying error message in an activity from a seperate public asyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am creating the user registration part of my app. I am using the `AsyncTask` class to handle this work on a separate thread. I have my `AsyncTask` class in a seperate class file. This

```
public class CreateAccountTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

private ProgressDialog mpDialog;
private CreateAccountTask task; 
private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private CreateAccount createAccount;
private AsyncTaskListener asyncTaskListener;


public CreateAccountTask(Activity activity, AsyncTaskListener asyncTaskListener){

    this.activity = activity;
    this.asyncTaskListener = asyncTaskListener;
}


@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        mpDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);

        //mpDialog.setTitle("Creating Account");
        mpDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
        mpDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mpDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mpDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //task.cancel(true);
                mpDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        mpDialog.show();

    }


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String fphoneNo = arg0[1];
    String fpassword = arg0[0];

    // create instance of the parseUser Class
    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
    newUser.setUsername(fphoneNo);
    newUser.setPassword(fpassword);

    // here Check if progress dialog has been cancelled

    if (!isCancelled()){

    // if dialog has not been cancelled create the new user here
    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {

                  // Something went wrong Sorry!

            if(e != null ){


                if(!isCancelled()){
                mpDialog.dismiss();

                String errorMessage = e.getMessage().toString();

                ErrorHappened(errorMessage);

                }

                else{

                    String errorMessage = "Registration Cancelled!";
                    ErrorHappened(errorMessage);

                }

            }

            // No Problems 
            else {
                if (!isCancelled()) {

                    // Wait for five seconds before starting the activity
                    //verifyingUser();

                }
                else {
                    String errorMessage = "Registration Cancelled2!";
                    ErrorHappened(errorMessage);

                    //Delete user in background
                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        currentUser.deleteInBackground();
                    }

                }
            }   

            }

                    });

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    asyncTaskListener.onTaskComplete(result);
}

private void ErrorHappened(String errorMessage) {

    Crouton CreateMagic = Crouton.makeText(createAccount, errorMessage, CroutonClass.ALERT);
    CreateMagic.setConfiguration(CroutonClass.configure);
    CreateMagic.show();


}





}
```

In my `onPreExecute` method, i start a progressDialog that shows while the background task is being executed. While in my `doInBackground` method i have i get the username and password supplied by the user in the main Activity and sign up the user. This is where my problem begins, If an error occurs during the user registration, i want to notify the user of this error using a Crouton (A cooler version of a toast). But the app crashes when it gets to the point of displaying the error with the crouton.

My question is:

1. How do i display the error message in my activity?
  2.

here is my Activity:

```
public class CreateAccount extends ActionBarActivity implements AsyncTaskListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);


    mPassWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mcreateAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createAcct);
    mPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Phone_Number);



    // create account Method
    createAccount();    

    }//end of on create.


    public void createAccount() {

    mcreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


                CreateAccountTask newTask = new CreateAccountTask(CreateAccount.this, new CreateAccount());
                newTask.execute(passwordString, fpartphoneNo);



            });

}






private void verifyingUser() {


}

private void shitHappened(String errorMessage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Crouton CreateMagic = Crouton.makeText(this, errorMessage, CroutonClass.ALERT);
    CreateMagic.setConfiguration(CroutonClass.configure);
    CreateMagic.show();


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
    super.onBackPressed();
}








@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

}
```

Comment: you can not able to do UI related work within doInBackground() try runOnUIThread or handler to work with UI.

Comment: @sathish Please I dont understand. Could you explain, with an example perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications and any other UI manipulation is only allowed from the UIThread. If you look at the documentation of `AsyncTask`, `doInBackground()` runs on its own Thread, while `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` and `onCancelled()` run on the UIThread.

In your case, you should use `protected void onCancelled(String result)` for the Notification. This runs on the UIThread and helps you to distinguish between a successful and unsuccessful operations. To use this, call `cancel()` and check in `doInBackground()` if the operation was cancelled.

`onCancelled()` will then be executed instead of `onPostExecute()`

In your special case it could be a problem of the context, because you are storing your `CreateAccount.this` in the constructor in `activity` of your `CreateAccountTask`, but you are using `createAccount`. Try changing it to the following:

```
Crouton.makeText(activity, errorMessage, CroutonClass.ALERT);
```

Comment: Sorry that is not the problem I am having. I am trying to notify the UI that an error has occured. How do I get to display the message.

Comment: Tried it. It did not work. From my understanding, onCancelled is called when for some reason the thread is cancelled.  Lets take for example, I cancelled the task by clicking the cancel button in my progress dialog, in my doInBackground I check to see if the user has cancelled the the dialog so I can stop the task, then display an error message using this line ErrorHappened(errorMessage) showing the user that the registration has been cancelled.  But when it reaches this point the app crashes. Note:  it works perfectly if the asynctask is an inner class of the activity

Comment: `onCancelled()` gets called if you call `cancel()` in your `doInBackground()` and then return from it. Apart from that, I think it could be a context problem. See the edit.

Comment: Yes I just discovered that...its a context problem. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I uncommented the task.cancel(true) line I have in my onclicklistener. This means that when I click on the cancel button in the dialog, the asynctask is cancelled. Why do I get a NullPointException here

Comment: Is your task object set? Please note that you should open a new question and not add your questions in the comment of the previous one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49041/discussion-between-user2852119-and-super-qua)

Answer (score 0):

Use `runOnUiThread` as below...

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mpDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);

            //mpDialog.setTitle("Creating Account");
            mpDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
            mpDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mpDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mpDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //task.cancel(true);
                    mpDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            mpDialog.show();

     }

}
```